# Statically linked swift module not found in mixed Objective-C/Swift library

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a project with multiple modules in multiple sub projects which I am slowly converting stuff into swift and frameworks.   Right now the products are statically linked libraries.  So lets say I have library A and library B.  In B depends on A.  In A I have a base class in swift, BaseView.  In B I have a class that extends BaseView, SuperTerrificView.  Now, in order to use BaseView in SuperTerrificView it is defined as public.  In order to use both BaseView and SuperTerrificView in classes that are still in Objective-C, they are both marked @objc.  When implementing SuperTerrificView, I used an @import ModuleA, to import the library for BaseView.  Finally, SuperTerrificView get's imported into  and used in CommonViewController in ModuleB.   The problem lies in the generated -Swift.h header for ModuleB.  It adds a line, @import ModuleA to import the BaseView when defining the objective-c interface for SuperTerrificView and the compiler is throwing an error that ModuleA can not be found.

So the question is, how do I tell the Objective-C compiler where to find ModuleA?

**library ModuleA**

*BaseView.swift --*

```
@import UIKit
@objc public class BaseView : UIView {
}
```

**library ModuleB**

*SuperTerrificView.swift --*

```
@import UIKit
@import ModuleA
@objc public class SuperTerrificView: BaseView {
}
```

*CommonViewControllerC.h --*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CommonViewControllerC : UIViewController {
}
@end
```

*CommonViewController.h --*

```
#import "CommonViewControllerC.h"
#import "ModuleA-Swift.h"
#import "ModuleB-Swift.h" //<---- error in the header, ModuleB not found

@implementation CommonViewControllerC 

@end
```

*ModuleB-Swift.h ---*

```
...
@import CoreGraphics;
@import ModuleA; //<--- error here
@import ObjectiveC;
...
```

Currently, my work around is to disable C and Objective-C modules, but that seems like it should be unnecessary.

Comment: May be you have a problem with a dependency graph. Try to check "Target Dependencies" for ModuleB

Comment: @AndrewRomanov Module A is listed as a target dependency of Module B

Comment: Can you create a test project with same configuration? Why you can't use dynamic linking?

Comment: It's a time to implement new functionality vs time to update existing working code kind of thing as we have run into problems building mixed Objective-C/Swift frameworks, conversion to frameworks for all libraries is on hold.